# Failed to connect: 0

Tags: stream-socket-client

i got this error in sending notification

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094438:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert internal error in /nfs/c04/h03/mnt/181638/domains/s.aumenta.do/html/merckerbitux/push/push_ios_admin.php on line 50

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /nfs/c04/h03/mnt/181638/domains/s.aumenta.do/html/merckerbitux/push/push_ios_admin.php on line 50

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /nfs/c04/h03/mnt/181638/domains/s.aumenta.do/html/merckerbitux/push/push_ios_admin.php on line 50
Failed to connect: 0

please give the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue was solve
problem is in .pem files that is corrupted so i re-genarate it and it works . Please check for password and path for the .pem file.